# Possible to dock to 3rd party program?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an app that gets info from another programmer's app via AppleScript and uses it to turn a motor via serial port.

I'd like my app to be visible (on top) when the other app is. Docked? Child? Is this even possible? I'm from a Win background, and still a newbie to Mac, so I'm not sure I asked the right question....

I don't have access to the other program's source. The author may be willing to provide something via scripting.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  Can you get the other app to export some data that can then later be used by your app?

Comment: Possibly. What to export, tho? An indication it's on top?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [launch agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) with `KeepAlive` + `OtherJobEnabled` key.

> [OtherJobEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) 
>              Each key in this dictionary is the label of another job. If the value of the key is true, then
>              this job is kept alive as long as that other job is enabled. Otherwise, if the value is false,
>              then this job is kept alive as long as the other job is disabled.

Create launchctl plist and place that plist inside `/Library/LaunchAgents` directory or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory (to be invoked just for this user).

**Plist:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>appName</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>OtherJobEnabled</key>
        <dict>
            <key> labelof_another_job</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>yourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/yourApp</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now open terminal and run

```
launchctl load pathToplistFile // use sudo if file is in /Library/LaunchAgents
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm too new to Mac esoterica to understand the references you cited or to see how it's a solution for me. I'll have to study this carefully. My first task is to discover what a 'job' is.

Comment: Have a look at Agents section in [Technical Note TN2083](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION3)